# how to move decimal and comma points in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

i have a .txt file, where i have numbers such as-

```
99.69599  
100.7113  
101.7196
123.93
```

but whenever i am exporting them to excel, they become like this-

```
9.969.599
1.007.113
1.017.196
123.93
```

please note that the numbers in the .txt file in the US English format but the excel is in German format. so in the excel (German format) decimal point and comma are opposite meaning it uses "." to mean "," and "," to mean ".".

- US / English thousands and decimal separators: `1,234.56`
- European thousands and decimal separators: `1.234,56`

and the main problem is excel is for some reason shifting the decimal point when the numbers are being exported. can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: How are you getting your txt into Excel?

Comment: Out of memory, I have no means to verify the correctness: Please revise your "Language and regional settings" in the control panel. Then also look for a similar setting in Excel Options. Make sure the Excel settings OVERRIDES the general ones in the Control Panel. NOTE THAT THIS IS *DISPLAY* ONLY, the numbers are still the very same numbers you imported.

Comment: Is it an option to format the column in Excel as text?

I am using Office 2016, in Options > Advanced > Editing Options the separator can get changed

Comment: @rrra: I'm really confused about how much you understand and how much you don't.  You understand that the German-based Excel is treating period (**``.``**) as a thousands separator (and comma (**`,`**) as a [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator)), and yet you say "Excel is … shifting the decimal point", when that's not what is happening.  Excel isn't seeing any decimal point, because it uses comma (**`,`**) as a decimal separator, and it is ***ignoring*** the periods (dots) in your input, because it thinks they are misplaced thousands separators.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So, for example, it sees `99.69599` as the integer (whole number) `9969599`.  Then, since it thinks you want to use thousands separators, it displays it as `9,969,599` — except, since it uses period as a thousands separator, it actually displays it as `9.969.599`. … … … … … … P.S. I guess English isn't your first language? You probably should be saying that you ***import*** the numbers *into* Excel.

Comment: @Hannu: I'm not sure exactly what you are saying.  If you are saying the Excel is importing the numbers correctly and then just *displaying* them wrong, I disagree.  When using the German (European) decimal separator and thousands separator, Excel sees ```99.69599``` as the integer (whole number) ```9969599```.

Comment: @Scott, your explanation looks correct, but then what is happening with `123.93`?  Why doesn't it display as `12.393`?

Comment: I was wondering about that myself.   I live in the US and use English, so I typed `123,93` into Excel, and it stayed as `123,93`, but as text, not a number.   Excel doesn't know how to interpret it as a number.   Do you get `123.93` left-justified, when all the others are right-justified?   If your numbers start in cell `A2`, put `=SUM(A2)` somewhere like `B2` (or `Q2` or `X2`; whatever's available) and drag/fill down.  I expect you'll see `9.969.599`, `1.007.113`, `1.017.196` and `0`, indicating that the fourth one isn't even stored as a number.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce `9.969.599` for `99.69599` even after tried some other Formats too!! Could you write that how you are exporting Data from Text file to Excel?

Comment: May be you have tried Import data from Text file to Excel even during that Excel doesn't changed the Format as you have show !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things since the technique to do the work is basically already answered:

1) The issue arises because Excel is interpreting the text as if formatted in the German manner, so the periods, which are decimal separators in English usage, are seen by YOUR Excel as misplaced integer groupers. For instance, it would think "99.34567" is what an English using Excel-er would see as "99,34567" and that some goof placed the comma. It then fixes that for you and "properly" places the separators.

You can fix it before importing, which is easily done with any simple program like NotePad or WordPad, and you'll prefer to do so if you are importing the file by opening it with Excel.

If Excel is already open and you are importing into the already open Excel, you can simply format the column you will dump the data into as Text BEFORE dumping the data in, and then do the operations described in Excel. Whichever seems good to you.

2) DO NOT insert a single quote ( ' ) because in many, many cases Excel will NOT make that available to remove and you'll have a couple extra steps to do to get clean numbers. Maybe not ALL cases, but so very, very many...

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the comments (at time of writing) it seems as the "sane" (regional agnostic!) way to get this done is

- make sure the numbers appear as text intitially (after the import).
- Then do replace the/any thousands separator with a null string (""),
- followed by a replace on the decimal separator to the one that Excel actually uses.
- Then do an "Add zero" (or multiply by one) using Paste Special, making Excel's text-data **formatting** change into "number", after selecting all data.

The first step may require (need) some `sed`, `awk`, (insert favorite scripting gadget name here) or "python magic", e.g. inserting a single quote `'` before all numbers - which Excel interprets as a literal "This is Text" marker.

*The last step is:

Enter a 1 in a random cell, Select the cell and Copy it, then select the data you wish to transform and do "Paste special", select multiply in the dialogue, click OK.*